# dropdown value not getting updated on submit of the form jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form which has a couple of text fields and dropdowns. I am able to capture the value on change of the dropdown. But that value when it comes to the click of the form, is not getting updated.

```
$('#submit_form .required').change(function (e) {
var input = $(this);
alert(input.val()); ----> gives the dropdown value selected.

});

$('#submit_form').submit(function() {
$('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
 var input = $(this);
 alert(input.val()); ----> it becomes null here.
});

});
```

Any idea why its alerting null in the submit function?

Comment: forget about change function, you need just proceed submit function  to bypass all ur inputs and others there. And i dont think filter is required here.

Comment: I commented the change function..Even then the dropdown value is coming as null on clicking submit...

Answer (score 0):

This sample based on your code works fine, both in IE and Chrome. Are you sure you don't have any other code messing with the select's status?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="submit_form" action="#">
        <select id="test1" class="required">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#submit_form .required').change(function (e) {
            var input = $(this);
            alert(input.val()); //----> gives the dropdown value selected.

        });

        $('#submit_form').submit(function() {
            $('#submit_form .required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                alert(input.val()); //----> it becomes null here.
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```